# bitcored fastsync

Tags: bitcore

Is any way to sync bitcore daemon faster?

```
  Options:

-h, --help          output usage information
-V, --version       output the version number
-c, --config <dir>  Specify the directory with Bitcore Node configuration
-d, --daemon        Make bitcore a daemon (running in the background)
```

There is no that option in CLI, and I cant find nothing about config.json

Answer (score 2):

Syncing to the blockchain involves a lot of downloading, disk usage, and computation.

Look at what resources are being used the most, one of them will be the bottleneck. For me it was my hard drive that was slowing everything down, once I upgraded my platter drive for a high speed SSD it went much faster.

In your case you may be limited by your internet connection speed or your CPU. Find out which and upgrade it.